# Google Image Translation Issues using Chromedriver with Selenium

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, google-translate

I am trying to translate a small number of images automatically using Google Translate, but I cannot seem to get it to work inside the chrome instance created by Chromedriver. I keep getting the message that no text could be detected in any image I upload, while the same image will get translated normally on a regular browser instance. Does anyone know what causes this issue or has experienced a similar problem?

I am pretty new to browser automation, so I don't really know where to begin troubleshooting this, as I don't even know how I would go about identifying this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I think the solution is creating a new chrome profile to use with selenium, probably the temporary profile that is created in selenium misses some configurations. The problem is finding which configuration is responsible for this ahah